# How to find the exact value of $\tan(\sec^{-1} 4)$?

Tags: trigonometry

I would like to know if there is a general method to solve equation looking like this:

$$\tan(\sec^{-1} 4)$$

without using a calculator (you have to find the exact value)?

How to proceed?

Comment: Did you mean $\tan \left(\sec^{-1} 4\right)$?

Comment: yes, sorry for the typo

Comment: What about using the identity $\sec^2 \theta = 1 +\tan^2 \theta$?

Comment: [In general](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Tan%5BArcSec%5Bn%5D%5D).

Answer (score 3):

Imagine a right-angled triangle with one leg $k$ and hypotenuse $4k$ and angle $\theta$ between them.  Then $\cos \theta = \frac{k}{4k}= \frac14$ and $\sec \theta = 4$, making $\sec^{-1}4 = \theta$.

The opposite leg is $\sqrt{(4k)^2-k^2}=\sqrt{15}k$ and so  $\tan(\sec^{-1}4) = \tan \theta = \frac{\sqrt{15}k}{k}=\sqrt{15}$.  Now you may need a calculator.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\sec^{-1}4=\theta\implies\sec\theta=4$

Now, $\tan^2\theta=\sec^2\theta-1$

Finally using the [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values) of the principal value of $\sec^{-1},0<\theta<\dfrac\pi2\implies\tan\theta>0$